# Switch off the new Delphi 2010 Find feature

Tags: delphi, search, delphi-2010

In Delphi 2010 a new Find bar has been added beneath the source editor.
Though I sounds like a good idea I find it prettry anoying when F3 should be pressed multiple times for finding next matches. It works from time to time for me.

How I can switch it off and use the old search fnctionality?

Comment: "I find it prettry anoying when F3 should be pressed multiple times for finding next matches" Ok..., but how else should it work or in other words, what are you missing?

Comment: I think you're actually saying you preferred the old 'press F3 to go to next search item' approach and you want it back, right?

Comment: I agree.  There was no need to muck with Ctrl+F find.  For the things that a "modeless" find is useful for we always had Ctrl+E (incremental search).  The only problem with Ctrl+E was that it was sensitive to changes in the Ctrl+F dialog so you had to Ctrl+F to change behaviours in Ctrl+E when required.  All they had to do was extend Ctrl+E just a little bit and leave Ctrl+F alone!

Comment: F3 still works the same as it always did.

1 CTRL-F
n Your search term 
1 [enter]
1 F3
still works just fine and with the same number of keystrokes for a find, find again (n+3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to switch back to the old modal behavior. That code is gone. If you’d like to see all the results in a list, you can use “Find in Files” and choose either “open files” or “files in project” to keep the number of files being searched to a minimum

Comment: David, since you are an Embarcadero employee I must state that as a customer, I do not consider your answer to be **good enough**. The source code editor is a developer's second most important tool. If the new version of Delphi has (as I understand from the question) increased the number of keystrokes required to perform simple code navigation (Find & Repeat Find) - that's a **serious** defect! Personally, I will refrain from upgrading until it has been fixed.

Comment: Please clearly state your objection in a report to Quality central and I’ll make sure that it gets the attention of the appropriate people.

I believe you are mistaken and the number of keystrokes required had not been changed.

My answer was strictly on how to get a modal dialog and a list of all places a search term could be found, which seemed to me to be what the original poster was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how reliant you are on the latest versions of the VCL components, you may be able to run a slightly older version of the IDE as your editor, and use command-line compilation to compile your code using Delphi 2010. I have in the past mixed and matched IDEs in this way, but admittedly this is more difficult if your software is component-heavy, so to speak.

**Edit**: Moved my comment.